# Android wide color gamut - with Glide api do I need to set preferred color space?

Tags: android, android-glide

When i download a jpg using glide api for android and I load it into an ImageView, should I need to specify the [color space](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorSpace.Named) ?

I'm so uncertain what happens on something like a pixel 3 if I do not specify this, I have read that the color of the image will be distorted yet why does it not just default to `Named.SRGB` ? I find this strange

More info on the [topic is here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/05/wide-color-photos-are-coming-to-android.html)

anyway, my glide code would look like the following:

```
GlideApp.with(itemView.getContext())
    .asBitmap() //already converted to bitmap, how to specify color Space then ? 
    .load(data.getImageUrl())
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {}
        });
    }
```

Can someone tell me how I would specify the bitmap color space in this scenario ?
Per android guidelines it's highly recommended to explicitly accept a ColorSpace as a parameter. But how ?  I guess this can apply to fresco and glide etc.